# How can I write a large VHDL module and keep it readable?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

I'm trying to write the control logic module for a toy processor.  It cycles through the fetch/decode/execute states, reads and writes from various bits of memory, and sets a bunch of control signals.  It's somewhat large, and as far as I can tell it can't really be subdivided into smaller modules.

I don't want to put the logic for all of the states into one process -- it's hard to read, and the mass of intermediate aliases & signals are a pain when using the simulator.

I tried splitting each state's logic into its own process, but then I had problems with multiple drivers.

I also tried declaring separate procedures for each state's logic in the head of one main process, and had the process just call the correct procedure based on the current state.  This worked quite nicely, with modular "functions" and a more readable structure... **but** each procedure's intermediate signals aren't visible in the simulator (and maybe not accessible to a testbench?  I gave up before trying that.).  I was using ISim in case that's relevant.

Was I doing something wrong?  Is there some trick I can use to avoid having one massive monolithic process?

EDIT: code for the module is [here](https://github.com/achan1989/SlowWorm/blob/2ec8d45fe4ee29eaf8c90a57772e97f1312c79d3/src/control/control.vhd).

Comment: Demonstrating the risk of describing problems in the abstract signals aren't aren't subprogram declarative items (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 4.3 Subprogram bodies) you'd be referring to variables ("...intermediate signals aren't visible..."). Can you provide  a [specific programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? How to best represent hardware in VHDL is likely not answerable absent details or description.

Comment: Your linked control.vhd code isn't functional for reasons whose explanations won't fit in the space allowed by even multiple comments. I'd anticipate if you were to provide functional code the class of issues you might have with readability might be dramatically different.  For instance you should use a case statement in a single process instead of separate processes for states. Each process assigning a signal has a driver for that signal. For resolved signals the resolved value is the effective value. is_uop will always be false as will  is_call and is_direct.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be that you need to use an editor better suited to reading large VHDL files. I regularly work with 3000+ line VHDL files where most of the space is the logic of a single process, and have no difficulties reading them due to an editor that supports code folding.

I use Notepad++, but I'm sure there are other editors that can support folding on VHDL syntax. When I open a file, I press alt+0 to fold every possible syntax folding point then expand as needed to the part I'm working on. You can also use line hiding to fold arbitrary sections of your file, although that's a little more awkward to work with.

If you have large groups of related concurrent statements you can easily group them into a folding point with a `name : if true generate` which also allows you to declare intermediate signals outside of the scope of your main architecture (`block` statements work, but aren't supported by all tools). To force a folding point within a process I use `if true then`.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.5.3 Generate statements "Elaboration of a generate statement consists of the replacement of the generate statement with zero or more copies of a block statement whose declarative part consists of declarative items contained within the generate statement and whose statement part consists of concurrent statements contained within the generate statement."  also 11.8 Generate statements. Block headers  (ports, generics, maps) are not required to be supported by IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 8.9.1 (withdrawn).  Generate statements do not allow block headers. XST matches.

Comment: I tried using block statements once. I don't recall if it was the synthesizer or simulator that choked, but I had to use generates to get everything working, regardless of what the official spec might say.

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing a processor that implements the different operations in a giant case statement, then what you are really describing is a series of parallel functional units, feeding an output multiplexer. You might have an output that is driven, depending on the op mode, by the output of either a multiplication, addition, subtraction, some logic operation, a shift, etc.

You can easily design this in a modular way, by implementing each functional unit in its own entity, some of which might be quite simple. In the first instance, these blocks would operate unconditionally, and their outputs would feed an output multiplexer. You might later add enable signals, driven by your instruction decoding logic, that enable only the blocks that will be used in a particular operation, in order to save power. It might sound like you will end up with a lot of control signals using this approach, but if you put them all in a record, it makes the code quite compact, while at the same time allowing verbosity and readability at the point where a control signal is used, for example:

```
AddSub : entity work.AdderSubtractor
port map (
  clk => clk,
  enable => decoded_instruction.addsub_enable,
  a => a,
  b => b,
  mode => decoded_instruction.addsub_mode, -- This might be an enumerated type
  output => addsub_output
);
```

There would be other `_output` signals, and at the end you would have something like

```
OutputMux : process (all)
begin
  case decoded_instruction.output_mux_select is
    when ADD_SUB => output <= addsub_output;
    when MULT => output <= mult_output;
    when LOGIC => output <= logic_output;
  end case;
end process;
```

One bonus of doing it this way is that you might find it efficient for several of the functions to be implemented in a DSP block in the FPGA; you can easily design a functional block for add, subtract, multiply, written to target the DSP block in your device. The output of this would be just another input to your 'output' multiplexer. In my experience you should be able to efficiently implement many of your processing functions using a single DSP block (or a single entity that describes a few cascaded DSP blocks, depending on your data path width).

Personally I much prefer this approach of making the design very modular. In a recent multicore DSP project, I have only a couple of files that have ~500 lines, with the majority having 200 or less. This means that when I come back to a part of the design, it usually fits on one page, and can easily be picked up and understood in a very short amount of time. I also find that when implementing heavy pipelining to improve the performance of the design, having too much going on in one process or entity can make this job an order of magnitude more difficult.

Lastly, if functional elements are contained in small entities, you can more easily simulate, test, and verify *just* that bit of code in isolation, which in my experience allows the block to be signed off more quickly, while at the same time giving more confidence in the code. If everything is in one process, it is harder to have confidence that making a change that fixes or improves one thing, isn't going to break something else. Again in a heavily pipelined design, I find that it can be quite easy to change something that inadvertently causes the design to fail an aggressive timing constraint, so the simpler the entities, the smaller the chances of this happening.

Comment: I was thinking about one level up, but your answer is still useful and relevant (both now and later).  I suppose that my fetch/decode/execute stages are also parallel functional units -- my problem with multiple signal drivers was fixed by putting the stages in a single process, and I guess this had an implicit mux behind the scenes.  I should be able to go back to separate processes if I manually mux the control signals from the correct stage.

Answer (score 0):

As said, your question is hard to answer. How many lines are we talking about?

You could look up good VHDL code practises though:
- aliases should be avoided (not all tools even support then AFAIK)
- give signals/variables a clear name
- try to group functionality
- try not to change a signal/variable on 2 places separated by 500lines, usually there is a way
- if really needed you could consider using shared variables, introduced in VHDL93. (this will, however, not solve your multiple driver issue)
- do not forget the availability of records to group signals

About making your "intermediate signals visible", you could write

```
junk_proc: process(clk, rst) is
variable a,b,c: of_some_types;
begin
if rst then
//do reset stuff
elsif rising_edge(clk)
b:=func1(a);
c:=func2(b);
end if;
end process;
```

variables a,b and c (plain wires in this case) could obviously be visualized in any simulation tool.

If, however, you write b=func1(func2(func3(func4(a)))), do not forget that you describe all this to happen in a single clock cycle. Considering your description I bet you'll run into problems, but perhaps that's a good way of learning.